# unicode-math: problem with math versions and operator font --?

Tags: fonts, math-operators, unicode-math

When changing the math font using `\mathversion` under unicode-math, math operator commands (such as `\lim` or `\cos`) lead to an error message stating "math alphabet identifier `\mathrm` is undefined in math version..." (although three clicks past the error prompts will get to correct output).  The error message is eliminated by resetting the operator font manually, e.g., as `\setoperatorfont\symup`. The MWE below illustrates this behavior; it is set up to produce the error for the GFS fonts but not for the Fira fonts.

The unicode-math documentation (sections 4.4.1 and 4.4.3) seems to suggest that `\mathrm` should be automatically reset when switching math versions, but the error message claims it's not.  The problem can also be manually eliminated by adding to the preamble a command like `\setmathfontface\mathrm[version=GFS]{GFS Neohellenic Math}`; however, as I read the documentation, this should not be necessary.

So, my question is whether there may be something off in the code I'm using or in my understanding of unicode-math?

The specific choice of fonts is not important to the problem, so far as I can see.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[]{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX Two Math} 

\setmathfont[version = Fira, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Fira Math}

\setmathfont[version = GFS, Scale=MatchUppercase]{GFS Neohellenic Math}
% \setmathfontface\mathrm[version=GFS]{GFS Neohellenic Math}  %... unclear that this should be needed, but does resolve the matter if used...

%%%  Environments for changing text and math fonts
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{Firasans}{}{%
   \setmainfont{FiraGO}[Scale=MatchUppercase]\mathversion{Fira}\setoperatorfont\symup}{%
}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{GFSsans}{}{%
   \setmainfont{GFS Neohellenic}[Scale=MatchUppercase, WordSpace=0.7]\mathversion{GFS}}{%\setoperatorfont\symup}{ % commented out for illustration
}

%%% An equation and some text to use 
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Equation}{}{%
   \[ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \cos^{2n}\left( m!\pi x \right) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\ 0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational} \end{cases} 
   \]
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Proof}{}{%
   \paragraph{Proof:} If $x$ is rational, then $x = p/q$ for integers $p$ and $q$. As $m$ becomes large, eventually $m!$ will include $q$ as a factor\ldots%
}

%%%
\begin{document}

\Equation\Proof\bigskip

\begin{Firasans}
   \Equation\Proof
\end{Firasans}

\bigskip

\begin{GFSsans}
   \Equation\Proof
\end{GFSsans}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `\text{...}` instead of `\mathrm`?

Comment: Add an issue to the issue tracker of unicode-math (simplify the example, don't use firamath).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - FiraGO and Fira Math can be replaced by another free text/math pairing, such as Tex Gyre Terms and Tex Gyre Terms Math.

Comment: @John There is no need to use three math fonts, already with  mathversion GFS you can demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - OK, submitted brief version to issue tracker.

Comment: Just for completeness: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/468